# Does KVM put a firewall on top of guests?

Tags: windows, firewall, linux-kvm

I have been working on a project to build an all inclusive server in my home. This is to augment my networking/vm knowledge, and save my Mother money on our cable bill. It right now consists of:

- Kubuntu 15.10 KVM/qemu/virt-manager
- Windows 7 Professional (guest)
- MacvTap bridge forwards Windows 7 naitively to the network @192.168.1.124
- Optimum Smart router with UPnP client auto config
  enabled NAT network to connect Windows 7 to the Host directly (to
  share a 1tb drive on the host) so media files can be shared between
  both I'm running Plex, and HDHomeRun on my network.

I need the windows 7 VM in order to access 'copy-once' channels broadcasted by Cablevision.

I am using Xbox 360s as dvrs at every TV in the house. However, I just cannot get the extenders to pair to Windows 7 (cannot setup extender error)

I read some articles detailing which Windows firewall rules to enable to allow this (although its supposed to be automatically configured during extender setup) It continued to fail, so I disabled the firewall on Windows 7, and it still failed.

I forced all services, and firewall ports to open if they were related too: UPnP, MediaCenter or MediaCenter Extenders.

Because this still fails, I am lead to believe kvm holds a firewall over Windows, even though Windows has a direct connection too the network via the ethernet port on the ubuntu host. If this is the case, I am lead to believe have to add the ports for UPnP/MediaCenter to the firewall overseeing my kvm guests (provided there is one).

Is there a firewall imposing on my KVM guests by default? Can anyone suggest of the next steps I should take to get Media Center to see my extenders?

____________________________________ INFO _______________________________

qemu networks

```
 $ virsh net-list
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes
 htg                  active     yes           yes
```

Network Details:

```
   $ virsh net-dumpxml default
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>01ef9934-7b51-4361-b73a-25cdb1c05857</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='[censored]'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

In the above xml for my macvtap connection, I notice STP is enabled, I dont know if this is required/affecting my results.

I also noticed this is on 192.168.122.x, this is odd, my local network is on 192.168.1.x. However I can easily from the router assign the vm guest the ip address of 192.168.1.124 and remote into the guest, so I think this is just translated when it reaches my nic.

```
  $ virsh net-dumpxml htg
<network>
  <name>htg</name>
  <uuid>78170573-a44c-4373-9b7d-073e305e2025</uuid>
  <bridge name='virbr1' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='[censored]'/>
  <domain name='htg'/>
  <ip address='192.168.100.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.100.128' end='192.168.100.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

ifconfig:

```
$ ifconfig -a
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:ae:e6:cd:ee
          inet addr:192.168.1.120  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:aeff:fee6:cdee/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:102008293 errors:0 dropped:28 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:79392922 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:54158216877 (54.1 GB)  TX bytes:60446559345 (60.4 GB)

macvtap0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:68:ec:33
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe68:ec33/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:77195630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:67770623 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:39261799110 (39.2 GB)  TX bytes:54972441095 (54.9 GB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:34:1a:17
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:8f:77:10
          inet addr:192.168.100.1  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27276957 errors:0 dropped:132 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13399059 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:36495252228 (36.4 GB)  TX bytes:6713581721 (6.7 GB)

virbr0-nic Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:34:1a:17
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr1-nic Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:8f:77:10
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:e7:1c:15
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fee7:1c15/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27276957 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17422400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:36877129626 (36.8 GB)  TX bytes:6929607671 (6.9 GB)
```

--removed my wireless card, as this isn't part of the equation and lies dormant--

Comment: I believe KVM itself (not sure about libvirt) has nothing to do with this. No idea how your distro configure iptables (or maybe nftables) by default, or whether you are using the right kind of networking setup though.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to look at this. I have been at this for a few weeks, and the project is a long time coming. I'm sure you can understand the frustration of getting stuck at the 90% mark, AND finding nothing when researching.

Comment: Have you tried handing over the entire network controller with PCI passthrough? It's a bit of extra work, but if it fails you'll be able to rule out any problems with KVM or your host OS.

Comment: I did consider this when I was building this system however this is on an old i7-950 and is not capable of vt-d